# how to fix the "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in React"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

actually I`m working with SPFX webpart using React, really don`t understand what is the issue here, but when I debug it shows the blow screenshot.

trying to get the SP list items in SPFX webpart using React, during the map it getting error.
please assist me using the below piece of code.

[[image: undefied]]

```
export interface IRShowListItemsWPState{
  listitems:[{"Title":"","ID":""}]
}

export default class GetSpListItems extends React.Component<IGetSpListItemsProps,IRShowListItemsWPState> {
  static siteurl:string="";
  public constructor(props: IGetSpListItemsProps, state:IRShowListItemsWPState){
    super(props);
    
    this.state={
      listitems:[
        {"Title":"",
        "ID":""
      }]
    };
      GetSpListItems.siteurl=this.props.websiteurl;
    }
    public componentDidMount() {
      let reactcontexthandler=this;
      jquery.ajax({
        url:`${GetSpListItems.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SampleList')/items`,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json; odata =verbose;'},
        success: function(resultData)
        {
          reactcontexthandler.setState({
          listitems:resultData.d.result});},
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

          }
        });
      }

      public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListItemsProps> {
        return(
        <div className={"styles.welcome"}>
          <h3>Get SP list items using ReactJS from SPFX Dev </h3>
          <table >
        {
        this.state.listitems && this.state.listitems.length>0 && this.state.listitems.map(function (listitem, listitemkey){
        let fullurl: string = `${GetSpListItems.siteurl}/lists/SampleList/DispForm.aspx?ID=${listitem.ID}`;
        return(
        <tr>
        <td><a className={styles.label} href={fullurl}>{listitem.Title}</a></td>
        <td className={styles.label}> {listitem.ID}</td>
        </tr>)})
        }</table>
    </div>
    );
    }}
```

Here is the video [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyR9YB6rfFM&list=PLkNa0QIBAHZIY9YYmsKwkOfszcvO4YR0v&index=62) where I have gone through as per the same I have followed but when I try it shows undefined error

Comment: I think the error msg is pretty clear. `this.state.listitems` this is undefined

Comment: have you checked the value of `this.state.listitems` ?

Comment: I don`t know how to check but it seems like its blank

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
{this.state.listitems && this.state.listitems.length>0 && this.state.listitems.map(function (listitem, listitemkey){
    let fullurl: string = `${GetSpListItems.siteurl}/lists/SampleList/DispForm.aspx?ID=${listitem.ID}`;
    return(
    <tr>
    <td><a className={styles.label} href={fullurl}>{listitem.Title}</a></td>
    <td className={styles.label}> {listitem.ID}</td>
    </tr>)})
}
```

Comment: really appreciated to reply here, I have updated the the below peace of code(rest all same hence) with this.state.listitems && this.state.listitems.length>0 && this.state.listitems.map but I don`t see any difference still same issue, actual output from REST API list content is not displayed, any assistance please

Comment: Babak please find the above complete code that I have update the complete tsx file code. so that you will understand more details on the entire file

Comment: Note: I am sure, data is not loading from SP API to displaying that is why when I add webpart in the page, once added other data is displaying but what ever we loading that is not displaying so immediately its dis-appearing, don`t understand what could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

`map` method belongs to array in Javascript. In your case, value of variable is `undefined` and for that variable value `map` method is being applied. Thus, you are seeing that error as being an invalid value for `map` method.

In order to resolve/prevent this error, what we can do is that, before assigning variable to `map` method, we will do separate conditional check for that variable value to make sure that it will be a valid array. With that, you won't be having that error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class WelcomeTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const { listitems } = this.state;
    const items =
      listitems && Array.isArray(listitems) && listitems.length > 0
        ? listitems
        : [];

    return (
      <div className={"styles.welcome"}>
        <table>
          {items.map(({ ID, Title }) => (
            <tr key={ID}>
              <td>
                <a
                  className={styles.label}
                  href={`${GetSpListItems.siteurl}/lists/SampleList/DispForm.aspx?ID=${ID}`}
                >
                  {Title}
                </a>
              </td>
              <td className={styles.label}> {ID}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all really thanks for prompt reply, unfortunately I don`t see any output with the above code as well, its sill blank and same error I don't know how to post here screenshot , but i don`t see any error in the code only error i see from inspect element console it display like same as the above screen shot like undefined

Comment: Hivar please find the above complete code that I have update the complete tsx file code. so that you will understand more details on the entire file so that you can assist me with piece of code

Comment: Note: I am sure, data is not loading from SP API to displaying that is why when I add webpart in the page, once added other data is displaying but what ever we loading that is not displaying so immediately its dis-appearing, don`t understand what could be the issue

Comment: @kmuralikrishna I saw your updated code. At first glance, it appears to have issue in your API call. I am not sure why you would need to add `jquery` for API call. Avoid using `jquery` with React.

```jsx
componentDidMount() {
  const url = `${GetSpListItems.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SampleList')/items`;
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
  fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers, redirect: "follow" })
    .then((d) => d.json())
    .then((d) => this.setState({ listitems: d.d.result }))
    .catch((d) => {});
}
```

Comment: @kmuralikrishna You may try above code and put console logs to track variable values before and after the API call.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, it was completely my mistake
I missed to letter "S" from, actually it was **results** missed the letter s
really thanks for help/assistance

```
listitems:resultData.d.results
```